# Como mostrar datos json en HTML

Tags: php, ajax, json

Mi problema es el siguiente, necesito imprimir los datos de un json en HTML,lo que requiero hacer es tener un input de búsqueda por cédula o numero de identificación, y que al presionar buscar me muestre en un formulario los datos que coincidan con ese numero para así poder editarlos, lo que he intentado es lo siguiente:

PETICIÓN AJAX

```
function viewPersona(){
 var result;
 jQuery(document).on('submit','#form_busqueda', function(event){
 event.preventDefault();

jQuery.ajax({
  url:'ajax.php?mode=view_persona',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: $(this).serialize(),
})

   .done(function(resp){
      console.log(resp);
      if(resp.respuesta == '0'){
        result = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-fill alert-close alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">';
        result += '<center><h3>Llena el campo</h3></center></div>';
        $('#resultado').html(result);
      } else {
        if(resp.respuesta == 'vacio'){
          $("#loading").hide();
          result = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-fill alert-close alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">';
          result += '<center><h3>No existen registros con esta cedula</h3></center></div>';
          $('#resultado').html(result);
        } else {
          for(var i = 0; i< resp.respuesta.length; i++){
            var cod = resp.respuesta[i].inpersonas;
            var nombres = resp.respuesta[i].nombre;
            var ape = resp.respuesta[i].apellido;
            var cedula = resp.respuesta[i].cedula;
            var email = resp.respuesta[i].email;
            var date = resp.respuesta[i].fechanacimiento;
            var estado = resp.respuesta[i].tkd_estado;
            var perfil = resp.respuesta[i].perfiles;
          }
          result = '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + nombres + '" readonly></fieldset></div>';
          $("#AJAX_MOD_IN").html(result);
        }
      }
  })
 });
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
 if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
 strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
  if(!empty($_POST['busqueda'])){
   $db = new Conexion();
   sleep(1);
   $busqueda = $_POST['busqueda'];
   $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tkd_personas INNER JOIN tkd_estados ON tkd_personas.id_estado = tkd_estados.id_estado WHERE tkd_personas.cedula = ? LIMIT 1");
    $sql->execute(array($busqueda));
     if($db->rows($sql)>0){
       $row = $db->recorrer($sql);
       echo json_encode(array('respuesta'=>$row));
     } else {
       echo json_encode(array('respuesta'=>'vacio'));
     }
   } else {
     echo json_encode(array('respuesta'=>'0'));
   }
  } else {
    header('location:?view=index');
  }
 ?>
```

Y ESTE ES EL JSON QUE ME MUESTRA console.log

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El formulario lo esta mostrando, pero cuando imprimo el dato dentro del value del input, me dice undefined.!

Gracias de antemano a quien me ayude!

Comment: Por favor añade un ejemplo de json que recibes para hacer unos una idea de la estructura.

Comment: He editado la pregunta Xerif

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que parece en el último `else` no estás accediendo al objeto "respuesta" (o al que contenga los datos devueltos)

```
success
Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )

    else {
              for(var i = 0; i< resp.respuesta.length; i++){
                var cod = resp.respuesta[i].inpersonas;
                var nombres = resp.respuesta[i].nombre;
                var ape = resp.respuesta[i].apellido;
                var cedula = resp.respuesta[i].cedula;
                var email = resp.respuesta[i].email;
                var date = resp.respuesta[i].fechanacimiento;
                var estado = resp.respuesta[i].tkd_estado;
                var perfil = resp.respuesta[i].perfiles;
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que **no das a conocer la estructura de lo que recibes** con ajax, por tanto es imposible saber exactamente qué es lo que falla. Deberías poner el resultado del console.log para que podamos ver lo que te manda el servidor. Por mi parte he hecho una interpretación de lo que te puede estar ocurriendo.

Para ello lo que **interpreto es que resp.respuesta es el "ok"** de que recibes la respuesta correctamente, por tanto hay que recorrer otro array que tengas a la par de la variable respuesta, que interpreto que es resp.datos.

Me he imaginado que en el json tienes un array de este estilo:

```
resp: {
 respuesta: '',
 datos: {
         {
          inpersonas: '',
          nombre: '',
          apellido:'',
          cedula:'',
          email:'',
          fechanacimiento:'',
          tkd_estado:'',
          perfiles:''
         },

        {
          inpersonas: '',
          nombre: '',
          apellido:'',
          cedula:'',
          email:'',
          fechanacimiento:'',
          tkd_estado:'',
          perfiles:''
         },
         //(repetido x veces...)
        }

}
```

**Por tanto deberías recorrer el array así:**

```
else {
      for(var i = 0; i< resp.datos.length; i++){
        var cod = resp.datos[i].inpersonas;
        var nombres = resp.datos[i].nombre;
        var ape = resp.datos[i].apellido;
        var cedula = resp.datos[i].cedula;
        var email = resp.datos[i].email;
        var date = resp.datos[i].fechanacimiento;
        var estado = resp.datos[i].tkd_estado;
        var perfil = resp.datos[i].perfiles;
      }
```

Comment: He editado la pregunta Antonio, con toda la estructura